# Is It Possible To Copy Object From Source S3 To Specific Path In Destination S3 Using The AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am able to copy an object from my source s3 to a destination s3, however my object always ends up in the root directory. Is it possible to specify a certain path during the [copy_object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#copy_object-instance_method)?

Are there any other alternatives or do I have to first copy to root and then move it to desired path?

Comment: CLI or SDK? If SDK, what language? The link you have given is for Ruby. Make your question complete with all required info.

Comment: @helloV Ruby SDK. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key:` is the full path where you want the file to go, in the target bucket -- not just the filename.

Setting this to (e.g.) `'assets/pictures/funny/cat.png'` will do what you expect.